# Как отсортировать foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Есть список который формирует foreach

Допустим такой

```
<a href="/test1">test1</a>
<a href="/test2">test2</a>
<a href="/test3">test3</a>
<a href="/test4">test4</a>
<a href="/test5">test5</a>
<a href="/test6">test6</a>
<a href="/test7">test7</a>
```

Вопрос как сделать так что бы допустим 5 ссылка стала первой в очереди и список получился таким

```
<a href="/test5">test5</a>
<a href="/test1">test1</a>
<a href="/test2">test2</a>
<a href="/test3">test3</a>
<a href="/test4">test4</a>
<a href="/test6">test6</a>
<a href="/test7">test7</a>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php и сортируйте как хотите

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать если вам не сложно как это сделать? я не как не могу понять как можно 5 сделать первым?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276313/php-move-associative-array-element-to-beginning-of-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помоему, foreach перебирает уже имеющийся список, а не формирует. Например у нас есть массив $tests. Внутри foreach используется вывод элементов массива, примерно в таком виде(этот пример с использованием шаблонизатора blade фреймворка laravel):

```
@foreach ($tests as $test)
    {{ $test }} 
@endforeach
```

Который как раз может выдать результат, как в вашем примере, то вот так можно сделать вывод 5го элемента первым(отсчет с нуля)

```
{{ tests[4] }}
```

А так вывести все остальные:

```
@foreach($tests as $index => $test)
    @If ($index != 4)
        {{$test}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Если используется чистый php, то так можно сделать вывод:

```
echo $tests[4] ;
foreach ($tests as $key => $test) {
    if($key != 4) {
        echo $test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут вариантов несколько.. Вам либо до `foreach`  формировать массив нужный и выводить уже в цикле, либо же, как выше написали, просто выборочно выводить что и где нужно..
Сменить эл-т в массиве (аля 5 пункт первым поставить) как вы написали можно как-то так:

```
$array = array_splice($array,array_search('key_from_array',array_keys($array)),1) + $array;
```

Соответственно, `key_from_array` это ключ эл-та, который нужно "переместить" вверх. Так-то способов это сделать много. В зависимости от необходимых изменений и стоит применять тот или иной